# Angular 2 Form Design

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm new both to web development and Angular 2 and am looking for general advice on how to design a form. The requirements are as follows

1. There is a separate page for the inputs and the results.
2. When the submit button on the inputs page is pressed an API call is made and the results of the call are presented on the results page.
3. On the results page there should be a back button with which one can navigate to the inputs page (and inputs are set to the value before submission). Ideally one could also use the back button of the browser to this end and pressing the browser refresh button would present the same results.

What components should be developed (e.g. parent component, inputs component and results component?), how should they interact and which URLs/routing should be used to meet the requirements. A main point of difficulty for me is the back functionality (requirement 3.).

Comment: To implement a 'back' functionality I would create a service to store both input values and results.

Comment: I suggest to check official Angular tutorial: https://angular.io/tutorial This tutorial covers your requerements.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Angular2+,

As you have a form and a result page, I would go on a 2 component basis.

Your form component should contain the following:

- Your HTML template with your form (please refer to [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol) tutorial on Model-Driven Forms in Angular 2 as I find them very useful)
- Your component class that will contain the method called when your submit button is clicked, it will retrieve the values inputted in the form and pass them to a method in your service that will do the http requests to your API.

Said method should look somewhat like the following:

```
this.myAwesomeService.myAPICall(this.formData)
            .subscribe(data => {
                // You will arrive here once the API call has returned something
                // We then redirect to your second page 
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/my/secondpage/url');
            }, error => {
                // Error handling here
            });
```

In order to retrieve the data in the next page I would suggest creating a service that will contain all the data needed.

A [service](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/20/Angular-2-Services-Tutorial---Understanding-&-Creating-Them) "is simply a javascript function, along with its associated properties and methods, that can be included (via dependency injection) into Angular 2 components. They allow you to develop code for specific tasks that can be used in those components.".

Therefore in your final page component, you could do something like this:

```
constructor(private location: Location,                                
            private myAwesomeService: MyService) {
   console.log(myAwesomeService.getData());
}
```

On a final note, you may have noted the `private location: Location` injection in the constructor of the second component, that could be used to go "back" like such:

```
doBack() {
    this.location.back();
}
```